# OpenGL VBO with single float per Vertex problem

Tags: java, opengl, vbo, vao, vertex-array-object

I have been stuck all day yesterday with this problem and cant figure it out. The code is below but generally i am trying to give a mesh Vertex Attributes for 1.Postions 2.Indices 3.Normals and 4.a single float value.
The values are all stored in different VBOs and after binding each vbo i declare the `vertexAttribPointer`. I cant get both normals and float value working. What im seeing seems like the position of the float value is either the x y or z part of the normals `vec3` in the previous vbo.

```java
GL4 gl = GLContext.getCurrentGL().getGL4();

int[] vaoids = new int[1];
gl.glGenVertexArrays(1,vaoids,0);

int[] vboids = new int[4];
gl.glGenBuffers(4,vboids,0);

gl.glBindVertexArray(vaoids[0]);

FloatBuffer verticesBuffer = FloatBuffer.allocate(mesh.vertices.length);
verticesBuffer.put(mesh.vertices);
verticesBuffer.flip();

gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboids[0]);
gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vertices.length * 4 ,verticesBuffer,gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
verticesBuffer.clear();
verticesBuffer = null;

//normal buffer
FloatBuffer normalBuffer = FloatBuffer.allocate(mesh.normals.length);
normalBuffer.put(mesh.normals);
normalBuffer.flip();

gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboids[2]);
gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.normals.length * 4 ,normalBuffer,gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, gl.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
normalBuffer.clear();
normalBuffer = null;


//color buffer
float[] colors = new float[mesh.vertices.length/3];
Arrays.fill(colors,255.0f);
FloatBuffer colorBuffer = FloatBuffer.allocate(colors.length);
colorBuffer.put(colors);
colorBuffer.flip();

gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboids[3]);
gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colors.length * 4 ,colorBuffer,gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(3, 1, gl.GL_FLOAT,false, 0, 0);
colorBuffer.clear();
colorBuffer = null;

IntBuffer indicesBuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(mesh.indices.length);
indicesBuffer.put(mesh.indices);
indicesBuffer.flip();

gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboids[1]);
gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.indices.length * 4 ,indicesBuffer,gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(1, mesh.type.equals(MeshType.TRIANGLE) ? 3 : mesh.type.equals(MeshType.LINE) ? 2 : mesh.type.equals(MeshType.POINT) ? 1:0, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, false, 0, 0);
indicesBuffer.clear();
indicesBuffer = null;

//gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
gl.glBindVertexArray(0);
```

This the code that declares the vao and vbos. I render with `glDrawElements` and enable the needed VertexAttributeArray Indices before that. In my Shader I access the value as following:

```c
layout (location=0) in vec3 position;
layout (location=2) in vec3 normal;
layout (location=3) in float color;

out vec3 normals;
out vec4 positionWorldSpace;
out flat float vertexColor;
```

And the fragment shader

```c
in flat float color;
```

I can get both of them working separate but if i declare both they float values are not correct anymore. The normals seems to be right however. As i said the values in the float seem the be values from the normals. Can there be some sort of overflow from the normal vbo to the float vbo? After hours of looking at the code i just cant spot the error.

Comment: I am sorry yes it is Java. Should have clarified

Comment: The indices are not attributes. The index buffer `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is stated in the VAO directly.

Comment: I removed the call to pointer after the indices and shifted the remaining attributes to position 0 1 2. But the same problem still occurs.

Comment: Ideally i want it to be of type short but for now since i couldn't get it to work i used float to narrow down where the error comes from. Basically it is an index that later tells me what material the part of the mesh is made of. The whole mesh is a triangulated point cloud with a marching cube algorithm.

Comment: You can't use `short` for an attribute, but you can use `int`. For integral attributes you have to use [`glVertexAttribIPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) (focus on `I` in the middle). Anyway, I can't see any obvious issue in your code.

Comment: I have seen that in the docs but afaik i can use glVertexAttribIPointer with a short but it will get casted to an int for the shader right? Anyways i think once i figured out how it works with a float i can just change it to int later.

Comment: Yes, the source can be `short` (`GL_SHORT` / `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`). The type in the shader has to be `int`. The attributes are converted.

Comment: I figured out my problem. In my vertex shader I send "vertexColor" to out but in my fragment shader I expected a float called "color". I works now. Thank you for your time and for the tips with indices and AttributePointers. I do wonder however how it got the values from the normal variable instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indices are not attributes. The [`Index buffer`](Index buffers) (`GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`) is stated in the VAO directly. See [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification).
When you use [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) then the order vertex coordinates of the vertex coordinates in the array defines the [primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive). If you want to use a different order or you want to use vertices for different primitives, then you have to use [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml). When you use `glDrawElements`, then the primitives are defined by the vertex indices in the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` buffer:

```java
gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboids[1]);
gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.indices.length * 4 ,indicesBuffer,gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// DELETE
//gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
//gl.glVertexAttribPointer(1, mesh.type.equals(MeshType.TRIANGLE) ? 3 : mesh.type.equals(MeshType.LINE) ? 2 : mesh.type.equals(MeshType.POINT) ? 1:0, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, false, 0, 0);

indicesBuffer.clear();
indicesBuffer = null;

gl.glBindVertexArray(0);
```

```java
gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, mesh.indices.length, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, null);
```

Comment: Thanks, the order of vertices wasnt the problem before but I did remove the pointers and shifted the remaining attribute indices up. The same problem still occurs. The float attributes seem the contain values of the normal vbo.